# How can we evaluate the graph by CDF?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, descriptive-statistics

Could you please help me to evaluate the graph correctly? Basically, the graph shows 3 lines which are early adopters of a convention, rest of the adopters and the all users. The x-axis is the number of in degree for a node in the network.(In degree means followers).

So, how can we evaluate this graph with the CDF?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of the CDF at a point $x_0$ is that it answers the following question: What percentage of my variable is less or equal than $x_0$.

You know for example that $60$ of All users has $10^1$ in-degree or less. You also know that almost $100%$ of All users has $10^3$ in-degree or less.

Similarly you also know that $70%$ (circa) of Early adopters has $10^3$ in-degree or less and so on for all the points of all the curves.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You are welcome, is that what you asked?

Comment: yes, exactly it is.